# Triple integral on E

Tags: integration

I want to calculate on E the integral $\int_E {{(z^2+z)z^2}\over {(z^3-z^2+z-1)}}$ dx dy dz.

E is the set born from the rotation around z-axis of $\{(y,z) \in R^2: y>0,2<z<5,z<1/y\}$.

I think to use cilindric coordinates $(\rho,\theta,z)$ so $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ but for $\rho$ and $z$?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you write correctly, the radius will depend on $z$, and the radius will be $1/z$, and so the new integral will be
$$
\int_2^5\frac{(z^2+z)z^2}{z^3-z^2+z-1}\biggl[\int_0^{1/{z}}\rho d\rho\biggr]\,dz\int_0^{2\pi}1\,d\theta.
$$
Here, the $\rho\,d\rho$ comes from the Jacobian. Since nothing depends on $\theta$, this integral is taken outside.